# Punctuation of a dependent clause for strong emphasis

Tags: punctuation, commas, dashes, emphasis

Which of the sentences below is correct if I want to strongly emphasize that the pencil is not is **not white**?

> - This is a black instead of a white pencil.
> - This is a black, instead of a white, pencil.
> - This is a black—instead of a white—pencil.

Comment: ... or throw in a qualifier like _deliberately_, _decidedly_, or _notably_, e.g. "This is a black, and `[deliberately|decidedly|notably]` not white, pencil."

Answer (score 4):

Or,

> "This pencil is black, *not* white."

Or,

> "Not white, but black this pencil is" (in Yoda-speak).

I prefer my first version, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I would rearrange it:

> This pencil is black instead of white.

But if you want to keep your original arrangement, the choice with the comma is most accurate:

> This is a black, instead of white, pencil.

Answer (score 0):

Use the sentence with the dashes. They add the emphasis you want by setting off "instead of white" visually.